# the prediction figures I got during training a semantic segmentation model

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I have tried to experiment with some existing semantics segmentation code against the ultrasound nerve data set.

The implementation is based on [u-net architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597).

During the training process, I can capture the verification plot for each epoch. In the following figures, the left one is the raw image, the middle one is the ground truth and the right one is the predicted one (or the probability map).

As shown in the following figures, we can see that the prediction for the epoch0  is just all black, then it seems to me that it started to capture some distribution of original image, then it gets all black again.

I just want to know how to explain the training process based on these plots, why it go back to the result of the first epoch after several training epochs.

Besides, why the predicted result tends to reproduce the distribution of original image during the training process.

Are there any insight can be derived from these training observations?

I generally followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation) to generate the training set. (I use the same function of `create_train_data` in the tutorial.
The only difference is that I add a background channel, to make the mask image with shape `(1,image_row, image_col,2)`

```
img_mask = io.imread(os.path.join(raw_data_path, image_mask_name))
img_mask = img_mask//255
img_mask_background = 1-img_mask
```

After loading the `npy` file generated from above, I normalize the raw image of training set

```
imgs_train = np.load(os.path.join(train_data_path,"imgs_train.npy"))
imgs_mask_train =   np.load(os.path.join(train_data_path,"imgs_mask_train.npy"))

imgs_train = imgs_train.astype('float32')
mean = np.mean(imgs_train)  # mean for data centering
std = np.std(imgs_train)  # std for data normalization
imgs_train -= mean
imgs_train /= std
```

I follow this [implementation](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet/blob/master/tf_unet/unet.py) to train the model. I did not change anything except this one

```
self.learning_rate_node = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=learning_rate, 
                                                        global_step=global_step, 
                                                        decay_steps=training_iters,  
                                                    decay_rate=decay_rate, 
                                                    staircase=True)
```

I change it to

```
global_step = global_step*self.batch_size
```

epoch 0
[image]
epoch 4
[image]
epoch 12
[image]
epoch 16
[image]

Comment: reduce your learning rate `base_lr`. It seems like your training diverges.

Comment: are you using any kind of regularization? It might be because of the gradient modifying the weights drastically, try using a constraint on the weight norms.

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing your model definition. But I would say there is something wrong with datatypes or value ranges that causes the model to diverge. Is all your data (mask, input) between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: Dear All, thank you for your reply. I have updated the original post.

Comment: What is the background channel ? Why do you add it ? Is it full black ? Does it work if you remove it ?

Comment: Hi Julien, the original implementation takes output map as a shape (1, width,height,2), the same as the u-net paper architecture. In order to fit the mask
image to this code. I add the background channel to the original mask image. What I did is just 1-mask. If I directly feed the original mask image into it, it will not run.
The code also provides a nice example, which artificially generates mask image as two channels.

Comment: `(1,image_row, image_col,2)` does this shape mean your batch_size is 1?

Comment: yes, that's data set representation in tensorflow. In Theano, I think it is (nb_sample, channel, row, column).